# Stubbing an action passed as a prop for unit test using jest in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs, stub

I'm writing a test for one of the private methods 'prepareUserCriteria' in my component 'UserDataView'.

This in turn passes data to 'requestProfile' method which is actually an action.

In order to test 'prepareUserCriteria', I need to check if my 'requestProfile' is called with correct data.

However, I get an error as follows -
"TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property undefined as function"

How do I fix this?

Here's the code:

### Component : UserDataView

```
prepareUserCriteria() {
 const criteria = this.state.searchCriteria;
 //Do some checks..
 if(...) {
    criteria = ......
 } else if(){
  criteria = .......
 } 

 return criteria;
} 

request(){
    //Do some checks...
    .............
    return this.props.dispatch.requestProfile({
        searchCriteria: this.prepareUserCriteria(),
        filters,
        ....
        //other arugments
        ....
        ....
    });
}
```

### Test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { requestProfile } from '../profile-actions';
import { spy, stub, assert as sinnonAssert } from 'sinon';
import { UserDataView } from '../user-data-view';
import moment from 'moment';

test('should test prepareUserCriteria logic', () => {
    const userSearchProps = {
        dispatch: spy(),
        joiningDate: moment('2018-12-12T00:00:00.000Z'),
        background: {},
        error: false,
        isCalendarLoading: false,
        clearFlightSelectionState: () => {
        },
        metadata: fromJS({
            userProfileType: 'EMP'
        }),
        searchCriteria: {
            address: [{ currentCity: 'FCO' }, { permanentCity: 'LIN' }],
            user: {
                firstName: 'John',
                lastName: 'Smith'
            },
            isValidUser: true
        }
    };
    userSearchProps.requestProfile = stub(requestProfile).callsFake(() => {});
    const userDataView = shallow(<UserDataView {...userSearchProps} />, context);
    sinonAssert.calledWith(userDataView.instance().props.dispatch.requestProfile, { 
        searchCriteria: {
            address: [{ currentCity: 'FCO' }, { permanentCity: 'LIN' }],
            user: {
             firstName: 'John',
                lastName: 'Smith'
            },
            isValidUser: true
        }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property undefined as function
```

Probably means that `requestProfile` is undefined.

```
userSearchProps.requestProfile = stub(requestProfile).callsFake(() => {});
```

Check the import.